# create a file in php

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have created a php file. The code i wrote for that mentioned bellow

```
$my_file = 'my_options.sql';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
```

After that i could not find a file under the my folder. There was a permission error like

```
Warning: fopen(my_options.sql) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/TantraProjects/Ranjit/nt_plugin/wp-content/plugins/option-url-changes/option-url-change.php on line 17
```

How can i rectify the error and make a file under the forlder. I dont want to manually give permission to the file. Is there any way to give permission create a file.Please help me.

Comment: try with `chmod(filename)`.

Comment: it is not php which prevents you from creating, it's the unix-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give permission to the folder "777" because you are trying to write.

Comment: He should try 755 first. Avoid 777 when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to CHMOD the folder via FTP / SSH / other means to 755 or 777 (if 755 doesn't work - better to be as strict as possible).